# “authorized as incorporated”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese, finance

> 1  As a result of four two-for-one stock splits on the Common Stock
>   effective October 20, 1989, May 15, 1992, August 22, 1997 and May 21,
>   2004, the number of shares of Series A ESOP Convertible Class A
>   Preferred Stock ***authorized as incorporated*** automatically
>   increased to 145,454,544 in accordance with the terms of paragraph
>   9(A)(1) of Appendix A. (This footnote is not a part of the Company's
>   Amended Articles of Incorporation, but is included to provide
>   up-to-date information on the status of Series A ESOP Convertible
>   Class A Preferred Stock.)

This is a footnote from the P&G Articles of Incorporation (https://za.pg.com/who-we-are/structure-governance/corporate-governance/articles-incorporation).

What does 'authorized as incorporated' mean here?

Comment: You shouldn't just [spam all the various SE with the same question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30399/authorized-as-incorporated-the-difference-between-class-and-series-of-shares).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It means** that the number of shares under discussion were [authorized](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/authorized) as [incorporated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incorporated). If you don't understand those words, you should really skip asking [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30399/authorized-as-incorporated-the-difference-between-class-and-series-of-shares) and English Language and direct your questions to the [English learners' SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

That said, if you were confused by which sense of *as* was meant, they're using it to mean “in accordance with:” *because of these stock splits, the number of shares of this series approved by the company in accordance with its articles of incorporation grew to 145-odd million by 2004.*